# What vimrc settings control syntax highlighting of indented awk code in markdown?

Tags: awk, vim, markdown

I cannot get   indented code to highlight in GAWK in vim markdown model

**Context:** I doing some literature programming in gawk. Comments are markdown syntax and code is GAWK, indented by a tab spaces.

**Problem:** I followed the doc at https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown#options. The markdown highlights as it should but the indented code remains white and bland:

[image: see here]

**What I did:** The first line  of my source code is

```
# vim: nospell filetype=markdown  :
```

My .vimrc contains the line

```
let g:vim_markdown_fenced_languages = ['awk=awk']
```

Which, according to the doc at SHOULD be enough to make that syntax highlight happen

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That information is not enough to get vim to understand how to highlight your block of code. ["Fenced" refers to code that is bounded by triple backticks](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown#fenced-code-block-languages) as follows:

````
```awk
this is some awk code that would be highlighted
```
````

This, when combined with the `let g:vim_markdown_fenced_languages = ['awk', 'sh', 'make']` etc lists, lets vim know exactly which highlighting syntax to use in a particular block.

You should also note that you don't need that particular vim plugin to get this to work; this is native vim functionality.

---

Edit: If you really want indentation, you can just indent the code block with the fencing:

````
    ```awk
    some awk code surrounded by indented fencing would be highlighted
    ```
````

If you were really hard-pressed to avoid the fencing entirely, the only way I know of would be to go into the actual vim syntax files:

```
cd $(vim -Nesc '!echo $VIMRUNTIME' -c qa)
vim syntax/markdown.vim
```

and try to figure out a way to force a default of awk highlighting on indented code, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: so is there some other way I can  write comments (in markdown)  flush left and see the syntax highlights for the code  (indented one tab, or four spaces)?

Comment: Updated my answer.